# String localization in React webapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization

I've been having quite a difficult time figuring out what the best practices are for localization in a React app.  I've found Yahoo's [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) library after much Googling, but I haven't found much else to accomplish what I want. That library seems like it would work fine, but it would be great to at least have more than one to compare to. I'm simply looking for a way to represent different strings in each component depending on the browser locale of the user. What library or method might I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth `react-intl` is *very* good. I used it on an enterprise level web application this past year, and I couldn't have been happier with it. The maintainers (I believe they are at Yahoo) are very pleasant and responded to any issues I had promptly.

I am not aware of any comparable libraries.

Comment: Thanks! Just started using it because of this answer. I found this intro very helpful: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/internationalization-in-react-7264738274a0

Comment: Great! Glad this helped :) I hope it works as well for you as it did for me.

Answer (score 2):

Before choosing an I18n library you might read this [article](https://medium.com/@jamuhl/get-your-react-js-application-translated-with-style-4ad090aefc2c) and this [article](https://medium.com/@jamuhl/i18n-frameworks-the-unfair-showdown-8d436cd6f470)...

Even if you specifically asked for React, I would recommend anyway looking into a i18n lib that is ready to be used in different frameworks, i.e. [i18next](http://i18next.com/docs/ecosystem/).
Perhaps your backend needs an i18n lib too? Or in future you want to replace React with something different...?

My experience shows me that i18next was right with "learn once - translate everywhere"

Further you should not only consider that you have to instrument your code (i18n) to get your app/website translated. You should think about the process too - how will you solve [continuous localization](https://medium.com/@adriano_55049/continuous-development-integration-and-localization-continuous-deployment-40ca6b9be771), how you keep track of progress, etc...

For a modern translation management system you might for example have a look at [locize](http://locize.com)... it plays well with all json or ICU (message-format) based i18n frameworks... and provides a lot more than traditional systems.